# How do I do a VLOOKUP in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am loading two xls Lists and try to do a VLOOKUP on the first List.
So I tried to set the formula exactly like I would in Excel, but that doesn't seem to work.
Google is no help, as I couldn't find any answer on how to do it (except VBS, but I want it in JAVA only).

This is how the formula looks:

`cell.setCellFormula("=SVERWEIS(A:A;'" + chooser1.getCurrentDirectory() + "'!$A:$A;1;0)");`

So, does anybody have an idea on how to write it properly?

Comment: You'd most likely need the english equivalent of `SVERWEIS` and change the semicolon to a comma (and possibly change `+` to `&`). But I have no experience in java and am not sure if the expected behavior would be the same as VBA syntax. Also right now, the lookup value is `A:A`...

Comment: Well my code and my excel both are in german and "&" is an invalid notation for Java. The Problem seems to be:
The specified formula '=SVERWEIS(A:A;'C:\myFilePath'!$A:$A;1;0)' starts with an equals sign which is not allowed.
And then the FormulaParser throws like 20 errors. I should have attatched this earlier

Comment: `setCellFormula` doesnt require the `=` at the beginng of a formula. Also I am pretty sure that you need to use the english equivalents of the formula as apache-poi works with the english version. You can check available formulas with `Collection<String> supportedFuncs = WorkbookEvaluator.getSupportedFunctionNames();
System.out.println(supportedFuncs);` and the unsupported ones with `Collection<String> unsupportedFuncs = WorkbookEvaluator.getNotSupportedFunctionNames();
System.err.println(unsupportedFuncs);`

Comment: thx, but that doesn't seem to work/help either. Isn't there a way to just write it into the Cell I want like a Text?Like it probably won't work but is there a way? :D

Comment: "my code and my excel both are in german": That's irrelevant. `Apache poi` does not interact with `Excel`. It creates `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` files. And those files always are en_US. Try `cell.setCellFormula("VLOOKUP(A:A,'C:\\myFilePath\\[myFileName.xlsx]mySheetname'!$A:$A,1,0)");`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that my notation with ";" instead of "," was the problem(and the language). Thank you.